# Nativescript stripe plugin expire date of the card

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using the plugin NativeScript Stripe(https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-stripe) with Angular. When i get the data dynamically from the frontend, the card number and the cvv are fine, but the expiring month and year are failing the card validation process. When I replace the dynamic month and year data with hardcoded values everything works great. Here is my code:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from 
"@angular/core";
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import {Page} from "ui/page";
 import {View} from "ui/core/view";
 import { CreditCardView, Card, Stripe } from 'nativescript-stripe';
 import { EventData } from 'data/observable';

@Component({
 selector: "Payment",
 moduleId: module.id,
 templateUrl: "./payment.component.html"
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild("card") card: ElementRef;
  constructor(page: Page) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Init your component properties here.
}

submit(args: EventData): void {
    let cardView = <CreditCardView>this.card.nativeElement;
    let card = <Card>cardView.card.card;
    const stripe = new Stripe('...');

    stripe.createToken(card,(error,token)=>{
        if (!error) {
          console.log(token.getId());
          console.log(token.getCard());
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
}
```

HTML:

```
<CreditCardView id="card"></CreditCardView>
<Button text="Button" (tap)="submit($event)"></Button>
```

When I try to print the card properties, I get the right card number and cvv, but both card.expireMonth and card.expireYear are giving me a 10 digits number, not a 2 digits one. I'm not sure if i did something wrong, or this is a bug. I've tested only on Android.

Edit:
This is another way that I tried that I think shows the problem better. card.expMonth and card.expYear values are 10 digits numbers, while card.number and card.cvc are the ones from the user input. If i replace the month and year with hardcoded two digit values, everything works perfect.

```
submit(args: EventData): void {
    let cardView = <CreditCardView>this.card.nativeElement;
    let card = cardView.card;
    const stripe = new Stripe('...');

     const cc:Card = new Card(card.number, card.expMonth, card.expYear, card.cvc);
         stripe.createToken(cc.card,(error,token)=>{
           if (!error) {
             console.log(token.getId());
             console.log(token.getCard());
           } else {
             console.log(error);
           }
         });
     }
}
```

Best regards,
Vlad

Comment: In the snippet above it is not clear how you are accessing & printing the card properties

Comment: I've updated my question to show the problem better.

Comment: Hello Vlad. I have exactly the same issue here. Did you have a chance to solve yours? If so, could you please be so king to share the solution?

Comment: I've used a custom frontend component, I got the data from it, and I've manually created a card object using the user input for card number, exp month and year and cvv. The cause for my problem was solved later (https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-stripe/issues/13), check if you have the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: Looks like the fix was rolled back after upgrading to 4.x. I do use the latest version and the numbers that I get in expMonth and expYear are strange (sometimes random) 4 digit integers that don't pass the validation.

Comment: Ended up patching the plugin's master branch with the change from above pull request. Works for me but should be included to their official release. Thank you for your help @VladStefanEne